# Прописная или строчная?

Tags: орфография

Речь о слове "Вселенная". Мне всегда казалось, что это слово пишется исключительно с прописной буквы, но сейчас в текстах я то и дело встречаю со строчной. Как же правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово многозначное. Написание зависит от значения. 
1. Вся система мироздания, весь мир - Вселенная( астрономический термин). Строение Вселенной. Тайны Вселенной. 
2.Вся земля, все страны - вселенная.  Объехать всю вселенную.
3. Разг. Всё население земного шара.   Ни один из всей вселенной не посочувствовал мне.